# Is there any difference between rm -r and rm -R?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rm

Title is Description. 
I just wonder there is any difference between `rm -r` and `rm -R`.

Linux man description is seemed like they are totally same(and one more, --recursive), but many people use -r and -R like they aren't same.

So I want to know about not only its functional difference but its practical(or conventional) difference.
Could anyone let me know about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the OpenGroup / POSIX specification for `rm`, the `-r` and `-R` options are equivalent.

Source: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/rm.html

This probably applies to all modern UNIX / Linux variants.

But it wasn't always that way:

- The `-R` option did not exist in v5 UNIX; see [here](https://www.tuhs.org/Archive/Distributions/Research/Dennis_v5/v5man.pdf), page 97.
- Or in v7 UNIX; see https://www.unix.com/man-page/v7/1/rm/.
- It apparently was introduced in 4.2bsd; see https://linuxgazette.net/issue49/fischer.html ... as meaning the same as `-r`.

The reason for adding `-R` was for compatibility with other commands that use `-R` to mean recursive.  (For example `chmod` ... where `-r` means "remove read permission".)

Answer (score 1):

Its the same.

```
# rm --help | grep directories.
  -r, -R, --recursive   remove directories and their contents recursively
  By default, rm does not remove directories.  Use the --recursive (-r or -R)
```

Answer (score 0):

The man-page mentions:

```
-r, -R, --recursive
       remove directories and their contents recursively
```

So, at least on my machine, it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

The two options are equivalent, by default, **rm** does not remove directories. And by using the **--recursive** (**-r or -R**) option to remove each listed directory, too, along with all of its contents.